# stop/start/restart java application from another java application

Tags: java, linux, centos, pid

I have two java application running on my `linux(centos)` system.first application done the processing and 2nd application **CONTROLS** 1st application.

Control Meaning (Perform operation on 1st application initiated from 2nd app ):

- START
- STOP
- RESTART

My 1st Application runs on static port `10001`

How can i perform these operation from my second application ? I found this articles which get me somewhat closer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14340719/1169180 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/138098/1169180

How can i get `PID` of application which is running on Port `(10001)` ?

Code :- eSocketServer.jar is my 1st application jar file

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "ps -ef | grep eSocketServer.jar | awk '{print $2}'");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
while ((br.readLine()) != null)
System.out.println("line: " + br.readLine());
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("exit: " + p.exitValue());
p.destroy();
```

It doesnt giving me any output by when same command is executed by shell prompt `ps -ef | grep eSocketServer.jar | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `runnable jar` of the program and START it from the  controller using:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar JAR-PATHNAME");`

Inside your first app , just get the `process id` using the following statement which will return you the `PID`. `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().substring(0,
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().indexOf("@")`

Write this `PID` to a file and have the `controller` read it from the file. `STOP` can now be implemented using the `kill` command in linux ( Run it the same way you ran the `java -jar` commmand.

Comment: does this same work for `start & restart ? ` and can i stop my 1st application in a more legitimate way ? i.e. `System.exit(0)` instead of `kill`

Comment: Depending on your exact implementation requirement , the approach may change. One I suggested is just one of the many approaches.